# How to create a list of Tuples from BeautifulSoup Data in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-science

I wish to create a list of tuples:

**Required Output**

```
d = [('Red','Apple'),('Green','Apple'),('Yellow','Banana'),('Blue','Berry')]
```

The HTML contains

```
<h2>
    <span class="head" id="Fruit">Apple</span>
</h2>
<ol>
    <li>
        <a href = "/red" title="Red">Red</a>
        <a href = "/rot" title="Rot">Rot</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href = "/green" title="Green">Green</a>
    </li>
</ol>
<h2>
    <span class="head" id="Banana">Banana</span>
</h2>
<ol>
    <li>
        <a href = "/yellow" title="Yellow">Yellow</a>
    </li>
</ol>
<h2>
    <span class="head" id="Berry">Berry</span>
</h2>
<ol>
    <li>
        <a href = "/blue" title="Blue">Blue</a>
    </li>
</ol>
<h2>
    <span class="head" id="Not">NotRequired</span>
</h2>
```

I tried, however, was able to get the data separately. And was not able to remove the headers that were not necessary. Also as the list are generated separately, the mapping is difficult.

```
box1 = []
box2 = []
for dat in body.find_all(class_ = "head"):
    temp = str(dat)
    x = temp.split(">")[1]
    box1.append(x.split("<")[0])
for dat in body.select("ol > li > a:nth-of-type(1)"):
    temp = str(dat)
    y = temp.split(">")[1]
    box2.append(y.split("<")[0])
```

**Output Generated**

```
['Apple','Banana','Berry','NotRequired']

['Red','Green','Yellow','Blue']
```

Comment: Why is it `('Red','Apple')` not `('Red','Rot','Apple')`?

Comment: Because I want to extract only first <a> tag from all <li> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use soup.findNext(class_="head")

and build the tuple within each of these calls

the way you are doing it, you cannot distinguish because you don't know how many of each type of fruit you have in terms of the colors list

Comment: Hey,
Thanks. I got the idea.
Still, it's somewhat getting difficult for me as I am new to this. Can you please help with some code?

Comment: after calling soup.findNext(class_="head"), find all colors within that head (fruit), for each color append (fruit, colorname) to a list

Answer (score 0):

You could use `zip` function(https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zipped = zip(x, y)
>>> list(zipped)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

So in your case

```
desired_output = list(zip(box2, box1))
```

Comment: That's not enough, `NotRequired` is in this list.